# LeadComponent() gives issues in getname() method

Tags: java, codenameone

If I set leadcomponent method, all the btns returns same name but I set different name for each button. If I comment out leadcomponent line, it works fine. What could have happened? I setName to all the buttons so that I can apply action listener and open different form according to the name returned.

My code:

```
BorderLayout gl1 = new BorderLayout();
Container middleContainer = new Container(gl1);
parentContiner.addComponent(middleContainer);
GridLayout gl2 = new GridLayout(counter / 3 + 1, 3);
gl2.setAutoFit(true);
Container gridContainer = new Container(gl2);
parentContiner.addComponent(gridContainer);

for (HashMap<String, Object> entry : homeStorage) {
  if (!"".equals(entry.get("img").toString())) {
    counter++;
    Button homeButton = new Button();
    id = entry.get("id").toString();

    imageUrl = entry.get("img").toString();
    title = entry.get("name").toString();
    homePlaceholder = homePlaceholder.scaled(screenWidth / 3 - 17, screenWidth / 3 - 17);
    encodedHomePlaceholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(homePlaceholder, true);
    Image btnIcon = URLImage.createToStorage(encodedHomePlaceholder, "home_" + title + imageUrl, allUrl.globalHomeImageUrl + imageUrl, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL);

    homeButton.setIcon(btnIcon);
***//set the name of button to id***    
    homeButton.setName(id);

    TextArea buttonTitle = new TextArea(properCase(title));

    buttonTitle.setEditable(false);
    buttonTitle.setGrowByContent(true);
    buttonTitle.setGrowLimit(2);
    buttonTitle.setScrollVisible(false);
    Container containerBtnTitle = new Container(new FlowLayout(Label.RIGHT, Label.BOTTOM));
    containerBtnTitle.add(buttonTitle);
    gridContainer.add(LayeredLayout.encloseIn(homeButton, containerBtnTitle));
**//if i remove this line(setLeadcomponent) it works (ie returns different name as set above, otherwise all the button returns the same name (ie last id)**
    gridContainer.setLeadComponent(homeButton);
    gridContainer.revalidate();
}
    homeButton.addActionListener((e) -> {
    if (homeButton.getName().equals("3")) {
        showForm("YoutubeVideos", null);
    } else if (homeButton.getName().equals("17")) {
        showForm("k2Gallery", null);
    } else if (homeButton.getName().equals("15")) {
        showForm("EmergencyCategory", null);
    } else if (homeButton.getName().equals("2")) {
        showForm("PartyClicks", null);
    } else if (homeButton.getName().equals("1")) {
        showForm("WhereTheParty", null);
    } else if (homeButton.getName().equals("5")) {
        showForm("CocktailRecipies", null);
    }

});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each container can have only 1 lead component.
You are creating a few homeButton but you have 1 gridContainer.

Comment: ohh sorry it was such a trivial mistake. Thanks @Chen